# Как скрыть блок по клику на на самого себя?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как скрыть блок по клику на на самого себя? При этом по клику на дочерние функция не должна срабатывать.
Подготовил небольшой код. Может быть есть какой-то метод, который позволяет выключить функцию, если мы не кликаем конкретно на сам элемент?

```js
$(".parent").click(function() {
  $(this).css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #FFC107;
}
.schild {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #512DA8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">

  <div class="schild">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам достаточно проверять цель клика с помощью [`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/).
Если это искомый блок - тогда обрабатывайте клик. Нет - пропускайте.

Вот ваш исправленный пример.

```js
$(".parent").click(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).hasClass('parent')) {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #FFC107;
}
.schild {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #512DA8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">

  <div class="schild">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант, чуть покороче...

```js
$(".parent").click(function(event) {
  event.target == this && $(this).css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #FFC107;
}
.schild {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #512DA8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">

  <div class="schild">

  </div>
</div>
```